# Is there any way to make steam ask for guard every time?

Tags: steam

Yes, I know it's weird! But there is any way I can do it from steam files?
For example, by editing the `loginusers.vdf`?

Comment: When you say "every time" are you including cases where, for example, you've told Steam to keep you logged in so you don't need to enter your password again?  Steam remembers my log in through the client on my home PC and doesn't ask for the guard code there, but every time I'm required to actually log in (ie: enter username and password), it does ask me for the guard code as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible by making sure "Remember me" is **not** checked when logging in. With that Steam will always need to re-authenticate to login.

And yes, changing the value of "RememberMe" to "0" in loginusers.vdf should force it to need to re-authenticate, or you can just logout of the Steam client.